# Calling stored procedure with JPA - pass a custom object

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, jpa-2.1, hibernate-5.x

I have a procedure on Oracle database:

```
TYPE r_age IS RECORD (id  VARCHAR2(100),
                      min  VARCHAR2(100),
                      max  VARCHAR2(100));

TYPE t_ages IS TABLE OF r_age INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE synchronize_ages (p_ages IN t_ages,
                            err_code OUT VARCHAR2,
                            err_desc OUT VARCHAR2);
```

I want to call this procedure using JPA but because of a type of p_ages I don't know how to do it. If the IN type would be a NUMBER or VARCHAR2 it would be easy, but in this example the type is more complex and I got stuck. Unfortunately i can't change this procedure. I use JPA 2.1 and hibernate 5.2.  Is there any chance to invoke this procedure?